# if (this.isSimulation) return;

Tags: meteor

I don't understand the usage of code where there's no block of code after if (..isSimulation) that instead just does return after which it follows up with an actual code that is suppose to access restful api from another server.

Right so:

```
if (this.isSimulation) return;
        var charsInfo = new Array();
        _keys.forEach(function (key, index, array) {
            EveOnline.fetch('account:Characters', { keyID: key.key1, vCode: key.key2 }, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
```

Comment: What is unclear? `this.isSimulation` is used to distinguish the actual method that runs on the server from the stub version that is running on the client to simulate (some of) the effects of the server method and thus improve the UX. If you don't understand a specific aspect, please include some relevant code and explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: Is this the whole code? You did not mention what you expected to happen. This simply means that the rest of the code will only be run on the server.

Comment: That's what I supposed, yet I don't under stand how the return; syntax doesn't end the if statement right then and there.

Comment: It does, but the condition is not met on the server, so the execution continues.

Comment: I get that part, but that condition doesn't have a body for code to execute, so it's just benign then right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most C-based languages you can omit the code block (`{` and `}` brackets) if the inner block evaluates to one statement.

For instance this:

```
if (x == 0) {
  x++;
}
```

and this:

```
if (x == 0)
  x++;
```

do exactly the same thing.  This works also for nested conditionals, like in your example.

So this:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
    if (i>j) {
      x++;
    }
  }
}
```

and this:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
  for (j=0; j<10; j++)
    if (i>j)
      x++;
```

are also the same thing.  The nested conditional/loop is seen as a single evaluated "thing" until it gets to the end.  Basically, the brackets defining the code blocks are assumed in the second example.

What you ***can't*** do is have a multi line code block not be surrounded in curlies.

For instance this:

```
if (i>j) {
  x++;
  y++;
}
```

And this:

```
if (i>j)
  x++;
  y++;
```

do **NOT** do the same thing at all.  In the first case, `x` and `y` are both incremented only if `i` is greater than `j`.  In the second case, `x` will be incremented only if `i` is greater than `j`, but `y` gets incremented all the time as it's not part of the if conditional before it.  This is because `x++` is considered one "statement" and `y++` is considered another, and only the first statement is assumed to be part of the proceeding if block.

Comment: Wrong topic, this is about JS and framework specific.

Comment: @janat08 I disagree.  The basic formatting for Javascript comes for Java, which was becoming very popular at the time JS came out.  Java formatting is itself based on C/C++ constructs.  That's not to say the language is directly derived from C/C++, I am merely pointing out the formating in this case.  Knowing that allows you to know what it potentially valid and invalid to do.  And since it's valid in C/C++ to have nested single-line blocks inside an if/for/while statement that do not have curly brackets, it is by extension possible in JS.  This is why I say "C-based" in the first line.

Comment: Right, it kind of clears up some stuff, but yea essentially it does terminate the function.